# How to find all swamp squares in a screeps room?

Tags: javascript, screeps

It seems there are only two types of terrain (so far), plain and swamp.  Is there any way to find all the swamp squares other than using `Room.lookAt(x,y)` for every square on the map?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Room.lookForAtArea`](https://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#lookForAtArea) method like this:

```
var terrain = creep.room.lookForAtArea('terrain', 0, 0, 49, 49);
terrain[5][10] == 'plain'; // tile at y=5 x=10 is plain land
terrain[25][40] == 'swamp'; // tile at y=25 x=40 is a swamp
```

Answer (score 2):

The [game docs](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#lookAt) do not mention anything specific. It seems to me you need go through the 50x50 matrix (each square on the map) and store the data in [Memory](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php#memory) which you can [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) through later to form a collection of swamp tiles.